# Eliminar signos de puntuación y espacios

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Cree esta función para eliminar los signos de puntuación y espacios de un string:

```
def foo(s):
    forbidden = ("?", "¿", "¡", "!", " ", ",", ".", ";", ":")
    texto = text.lower()
    for i, v in enumerate(texto):
        if v in forbidden:
            texto = texto[:i] + texto[i + 1:]
            print(texto)
```

El problema con este código es que cuando llamo a la función:

```
foo("Rise to vote, sir.")
```

El output es este:

```
riseto vote, sir.
riseto ote, sir.
riseto ote, ir.
riseto ote, i.
riseto ote, i.
```

El error puede verse cuando llamamos a la función con el siguiente argumento:

```
foo("?!¿¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:")
```

En el output no se eliminan **algunos** signos de puntuación y se eliminan letras. ¿Alguien podría explicarme porque pasa esto y como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por norma general **nunca debes modificar un iterable mientras usas un `for in`**, te encontrarás con resultados inesperados si no sabes muy bién que estás haciendo. Aunque uses indexación con un `range` vas a tener problemas con tu algoritmo porque modificas la longitud del array durante la iteración y los indices cambian por tanto.

Vamos a ver que pasa en tu algoritmo cuando ejecutas `foo("?!¿¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:")`:

> ```
> i = 0,   v = "?", t_ini = "?!¿¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:", t_fin "!¿¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:"
> i = 1,   v = "!", t_ini = "!¿¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:",  t_fin "!¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:"
> i = 2,   v = "¿", t_ini = "!¡.,:aaa?!¿¡.,:",   t_fin "!¡,:aaa?!¿¡.,:"
> i = 3,   v = "¡", t_ini = "!¡,:aaa?!¿¡.,:",    t_fin "!¡,aaa?!¿¡.,:"
> i = 4,   v = ".", t_ini = "!¡,aaa?!¿¡.,:",     t_fin "!¡,aa?!¿¡.,:"
> i = 5,   v = ",", t_ini = "!¡,aa?!¿¡.,:",      t_fin "!¡,aa!¿¡.,:"
> i = 6,   v = ":", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¿¡.,:",       t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 7,   v = "a", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 8,   v = "a", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 9,   v = "a", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 10,  v = "?", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 11,  v = "!", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 12,  v = "¿", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 13,  v = "¡", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 14,  v = ".", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 15,  v = ",", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> i = 16,  v = ":", t_ini = "!¡,aa!¡.,:",        t_fin "!¡,aa!¡.,:"
> ```

Como podemos ver el índice apunta a un elemento incorrecto en el momento que eliminamos (o añadimos) un elemento.

La concatenación de cadenas es por lo general muy ineficiente, no obstante algo parecido a tu idea sería hacer algo como esto:

```
def foo(text):
    forbidden = ("?", "¿", "¡", "!", " ", ",", ".", ";", ":")
    texto = text.lower()
    aux = "" 
    for  v in texto:
        if not v in forbidden:
            aux += v
    return aux
```

No se si se trata de alguna tarea o si tienes cualquier limitación, en caso contrario hay otras alternativas:

- `str.translate`:

  ```
  def foo(text):
      forbidden = {ord(c): None for c in ("?", "¿", "¡", "!", " ", ",", ".", ";", ":")}
      return texto.lower().translate(forbidden)
  ```
- Generador por compresión junto a `str.join()`:

  ```
  def foo(text):
      forbidden = {"?", "¿", "¡", "!", " ", ",", ".", ";", ":"}
      return "".join(c for c in text.lower() if c not in forbidden )
  ```
- También puedes usar `str.replace` de forma iterativa o `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con expresiones regulares.

```
import re
result = re.sub("[\w|_]", "", subject)
```

no he probado la expresión regular pero esa es la idea